# Firebase Storage: Object does not exist

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have the below code in my ReactJS file that is to upLoad a file to Firebase.

```
async function uploadFile() {
    console.log('starting UPLOAD ========');
    const blob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
    const path = '/recordings/one';
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(path)
      .put(blob)
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded complete');
      });
    console.log(`====> setURL is ${setURL} <=======`);
    storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL().then(setURL);
  }
```

The first time the button is clicked I get this error, but the the second time I click it then it works. Not sure what is going on?

```
Firebase Storage: Object 'recordings/one' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
```

I did notice when it fails this is the URL it is trying to hit (404). Notice the %2 instead of "/"

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/buerce.appspot.com/o/recordings%2Fone 404
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `getDownloadURL` method runs before actually uploading file. Both the `put` and `getDownloadURL` method returns [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Your function is async so I'd recommend using `await` for both upload and getDownloadURL methods just like you are doing on fetch method.

```
async function uploadFile() {
    console.log('starting UPLOAD ========');
    const blob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then((r) => r.blob());
    const path = '/recordings/one';
    await firebase.storage().ref(path).put(blob)

    const setURL = await storage.ref(path).getDownloadURL()
    console.log(`====> setURL is ${setURL} <=======`);
}
```